# How to compare code coverage of regression tests with introduced changes in PHP code?

Tags: php, code-coverage, git-diff, regression-testing

There is a collection of automatic regression tests for SOAP API written in PHP. I would like to run the whole suite, gather code coverage reports, aggregate them and compare with introduced code changes (by comparing master branch with dev branch).

That will give me useful information, which changes are not covered with tests.

[php-code-coverage](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/php-code-coverage) library has a method to combine code coverages, but as I want to run the tests concurrently, it might be impossible to merge them correctly.

[pycobertura](https://github.com/SurveyMonkey/pycobertura) can compare two coverage files and two code branches, so it will be required to smartly combine code coverage data from multiple runs.

Is there any better existing solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a tool for this: [phpcov](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/). It allows to merge many coverage files with *merge* option and compare with git diff using *patch-coverage*.